# jQuery UI datepicker 'setDate' method not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having some issues with datepicker in jQuery.

I'm trying to put the today date in a field which is a datepicker.

I've tried with:

```
$('#fecha_alta').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
console.log($('#fecha_alta').datepicker('getDate'));
```

And

```
$('#fecha_alta').datepicker('setDate', '+0');
console.log($('#fecha_alta').datepicker('getDate'));
```

But always log null and also the input shows empty.

What's wrong?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

(tested on the jQueryUI datepicker [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default))

Comment: And if it's not working it may be related with incompatibilities?

Comment: The easiest way for you to tackle this issue is to create a jsfiddle.net space with the most minimalist code for your to reproduce this issue. If the issue persists, you'll be able to share with us your problem and can expect a quick analysis from us folks.

Comment: And of course, when I'm using '#datepicker' you should use '#fecha_alta' since it's the ID you use. My answer was generic and can be applied to the jQueryUI demo page.

Comment: Yeah I know and your answer is one of the codes I put so... thanks for your help anyway. I'll test them :D

Answer (score 3):

If you need to set the date to the current one **by default**, then you may want to set it at start, when creating the widget:

```
$('#datepicker').datepick({
  defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set date like this as well

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date()).trigger('change')
```