# How to fire jquery datepicker onselect event explicity?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can we fire Jquery Date picker On select event explicitly on Page Load?

I am pre populating the date in date picker, so I want to fire an ajax call based on the pre populated date.

Thank you!

Comment: look into trigger function in jQuery

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan - I want to set a date in the datepicker when the user selects an option button.  For year option I want to set the start date and the end date for the previous year.  I can do all of this programmatically but the max date in the datepicker initializer is biting me.  I want to trigger the date function as if the user actually made a selection.  I tried the .click and the .trigger.  The .click did nothing.  The .trigger gave me this error:  Cannot convert undefined or null to object.  I'm still looking into it but hopeful you may have advice.  Thank you.

Comment: @Patricia, please have a look at `setDate` function offered by jquery  datepicker. To set it dynamically check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly