# jQuery Timepicker "Now" button not accessing current time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

This question deals with a third-party plugin, but there may be enough crossover with the stock jquery UI datepicker that someone might be able to help out.

1) Set a maxDate of 0 or new Date() is set in the datetimepicker options

```
$('.foo').datetimepicker({maxDate:0})
```

2) Press "now" button

!3) Now button does not set time to the current time, but the time when the page was loaded

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rf3gk/

How can I work around this? Is there a fix I can do, either in an external file or in the addon itself?

Comment: Why do you need a `maxDate` of 0? It's probably parsing that to December 1969 (that's what `new Date(0);` gives), and then updating improperly because now is much later than that.

Comment: It's getting the proper time. The datepicker API accepts numbers as date offsets: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be calling `setDate`, or similar in your plugin, see [jQuery datepicker set selected date, on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly).

Comment: setDate won't work as it won't set a new maximum and allow sliders to go up to that; I would like the "Now" button to behave properly.

Comment: @subyraman, ok, so why wouldn't you just increase the max date at the same time you set the date to now?

Comment: That doesn't increase the slider range and is causing the timepicker to crash when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foo').datetimepicker({maxDate: '0'})
```

This will solve the problem.

change `{maxDate: 0}` to `{maxDate: '0'}`

Comment: It does, but isn't this a partial fix? Now it will update properly, but the sliders allow exceeding the range past the current time.