# refresh the value of variable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm need your helps.
I used jquery to create datetime picker, and them work fine, but one problem :
When i set value to datetimepicker they set time load the page, when i'm try refresh the value of variable the jquery was crashed. Help please :

There is my code (failed) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var aaa = '{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}'
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
        .datetimepicker({value:aaa,step:10});
</script>
```

P.S. : '{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}' this is django now time

Comment: Why have you used datetimepicker() twice ????

Comment: i don't know if really, i used them for standart example, and this is working, but don't refresh

Comment: Try using once $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:aaa,step:10});

Comment: yes) thanks it's working too)) but problem still present, the value not change

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle ??

Comment: i guess yes can, but don't know how... the variable must be the available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("setDate", aaa);
}
```

Try this, if this works then try adding other stuffs.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly

Comment: try simple lile in example, clear field : $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("setDate", '{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}');
or like this
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
still clear field

Comment: When you click on your text box does it show up the date picker ??

Comment: What is the ID of your input field in which you are adding datetimepicker ??

Comment: sorry, i'm not understand

Comment: You are trying to add the datetimepicker to an input text field.. Am I right ?? So what is the ID or class of that input text field ?? Hopefully you must have added ID or class to that field ??

Comment: if really i'm not understand about what ID you talk,
there is the field input :
<label for="id_start_date" style=" display:table; text-align: center;">Start date : </lable><input type="text" name="start_date" id="datetimepicker" style="width:26%;  height:120%; border:1px solid #0099FF;"readonly/>

and this is django take the value :
start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']

Comment: id="datetimepicker" this is you ID... So hopefully your code must work. Have you added this inside $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: and again sorry, how i can change the value of variable in this example?

Comment: i'm try something
 id="$(document).ready(function(){$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}',step:10});});"
and no change

Comment: Sorry then. I have no other clue.

Comment: id="$(document).ready(function(){$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("setDate", '{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i');}" 
this don't work's too

Answer (score 1):

Since you din't link a reference for jquery datetimepicker(),
I assume you're talking about this:
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

In order to accomplish your task, you have to:

1. be sure that your timepicker starts after document loading using `document.ready`
2. you're calling `datetimepicker()` on `$('#datetimepicker')`, then you're calling it again on an already jquery/datepicker object, with new parameters. I don't know if it may cause initialization problems, but i can assure you that it's useless.
3. if you want to change datepicker value on the fly, you have to use it's own method like in this example: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#runtime_options

here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            value : {{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }},
            step : 10
        });
    });
    //below, an example of data variable refresh
    $('#datetimepicker').setOptions({value : {{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }} });
</script>
```