# Jquery date picker select highlighted month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a datepicker and here i highlight selected period.But i have some issue here,that is 
This is January 2017 But when i select some period of february then It's correctly highlighted in
february but Default it shows current month int datepicker that is January.

### Code

```
$("#daterangepicker1").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var theday = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
      date.getDate() + '/' +
      date.getFullYear();
    return [true, $.inArray(theday, dtrange) >= 0 ? "hightlight" : ''];
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to open the [jQuery Date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default) from a specific month, you need to set the [defaultDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489880/jquery-open-calendar-to-specific-month) of the date picker. For your requirement you need to set any day of February to be the default date of the date picker. Here is a sample code snippet. Here it sets 3 days of February to be default selected and sets first of February to be the default date. Hence your calendar opens from February 2017.

Here is a sample snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hightlight {
            background: green;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#daterangepicker1").datepicker({
                inline: true,
                defaultDate: new Date("2/1/2017"),
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var dtrange = ["2/2/2017", "2/12/2017", "2/22/2017"];
                    var theday = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
                        date.getDate() + '/' +
                        date.getFullYear();
                    return [true, $.inArray(theday, dtrange) >= 0 ? "hightlight" : ''];
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Date:
        <input type="text" id="daterangepicker1">
    </p>


</body>

</html>
```