# how to set server date on jQuery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

it return system date, i will set my system date behind two day. example: today date is 03 AUG 2017 and i will set date 01 AUG 2017 then it return my recent set date means 01 AUG 2017, but i need to use server date to display current date like 03 AUG 2017.

please help me and thanks to advance

Comment: Tell us what have you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker set selected date, on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly)

Comment: i will try this code: 
$( function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date() );
 } );

Comment: See comment on accepted answer in linked question: "use `defaultDate` instead of `setDate`, if `setDate` does not work."

Comment: `defaultDate` not work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure the default datepicker date is your server's date instead of the user's system date, get it via PHP and echo it in the `setDate` option of datepicker.

```
<?php
$now = date("m/d/Y");
?>

<script>
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", "<?php echo $now; ?>" );
</script>
```

Comment: I did sort of gloss over the server side datetime part. Good answer. Maybe not a dupe of of what I linked specifically...

Answer (score -3):

you should fetch server time by using code bellow :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var today = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
$(function() {               
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: today
});
});
</script>
```