# Set date on a datepicker jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a website where I am implementing datepickers, the site is for uploading school tasks, then I have a datepicker for the date on which it was commissioned (**homeWorkDate**) and another for the date that it should be delivered (**reviewDate**). The detail is more noticeable when you want to edit a task, at the time of loading the dates it always takes as reference today and not its date (**baseDate**).

I have tried with **defaultDate** and **setDate**

```
function setCalendarsDate(baseDate, homeWorkDate, reviewDate) {
    $("#fmt_d")
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: baseDate,
            maxDate: homeWorkDate
        })
        .datepicker("setDate", homeWorkDate)

    $("#fmt_e")
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: baseDate,
            minDate: reviewDate
        })
        .datepicker("setDate", reviewDate)
}
```

Comment: Hey Domingo. Thank you for including your question in Spanish *and* English. However, as StackOverflow is specifically an English website, please consider removing the Spanish portion and translating the title. If you prefer to ask your question in Spanish, you can use [*Stack Overflow en español*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: Did you tried `minDate` for setting starting date. 
For more details check here https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Not js expert,  by any means but have you tried ` $("#fmt_d").datepicker("setDate", reviewDate)` ?

Comment: @Ankur minDate is for the earliest date accepted by the textfield.

Comment: Can you show the date formats which you are assigning in setDate function call?

Comment: @stefgosselin Sorry I translated bad my code

Comment: have you tried it?? [date-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328040/7709509)

Comment: Thanks guys, it works, I just had to use **destroy**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this may help, credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/751843/604259

Seems you may need to pass an object as second parameter.

`$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );`

Good-luck

Comment: Not necessary to pass date object. Right format will work too. https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate